# If t is a quadratic residue mod p, how can I efficiently solve the equation $x^2=t \pmod {p}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that if $({t\over p})=1$, then $t$ is a quadratic residue, which means that $x^2 \equiv t$ mod p has solutions. So is there any skills or methods that I can use to solve the equation given a prime $p$ and $({t\over p})=1$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm.